# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Swift_Validate' not found

Tags: php, apache, swiftmailer

I am trying to use Swift_Validate::email($email) and I get a php error: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Swift_Validate' not found.

I have the latest version of swiftmailer. Is there some preference settings I need to do?

I have tried including the Validate.php file, but then I get the error: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Swift_DependencyContainer' not found.

I include DependencyContainer.php and I get the error PHP Fatal error: Class 'Swift_DependencyException' not found.

I include DependencyException.php and I get the error: Class 'Swift_SwiftException' not found.

I include SwiftException.php and I still get the same error.

I think I must not have the preferences set up correctly. I am calling:
    "require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');"

The code I am using for the validation is:
    if (!Swift_Validate::email($email))
        { $error = true; }

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Using latest Apache and PHP.

Comment: how are you including Swift Mailer at all? because if you used composer you wouldn't have that problem :)

Comment: Yes... I am including:  "require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');" Thanks

Comment: And where are you defining $dir ? perhaps you meant the magic constant ```__DIR__```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `require_once dirname( __FILE__) . '/lib/swift_required.php';` to use the built-in autoloader, where `lib` is subfolder of folder where is the current file ( for default directory structure of the library )

Comment: Thanks! for some reason it didn't like my 
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
I placed the include as you wrote it at the top of the PHP and it worked. Thanks to you and amenadiel. Much appreciated.